# Label -> Alert Controller Textfield? Can I edit pre-existing text from a label, in a textfield in an alert controller? Swift 3, Xcode 8, IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, label, textfield, uialertcontroller

Basically, [i have an alert controller set up so that when i click a button in the view controller, an alert controller pops up and i can type words into a textfield, click an "OK" button](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png) and it inserts that text into a label in the view controller. Ive extended this ability so that i can have [preset keywords (like "Good," "Likely" and "Almost") that i can select from in the alert controller to speed up the typing process, as these words are typed a lot in my app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHrJt.png) I was wondering if you could also edit those key words that I've selected? Every time i try to add text to whatever text is in the label i have to start from a blank textfield.

Specifically, whatever text that is already in my label, can i have that text ready in my textfield to edit, next time i pull up the alert controller?

This is what i have so far, for the second image:

```
//Editable Text Box with Preset Keywords

@IBOutlet weak var UselessLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func UselessTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Useless Button Tapped")
    openUselessAlert()

}

func openUselessAlert() {

    //Create Alert Controller
    let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Uselss:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Good", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Good"}

    alert9.addAction(bt1)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Likely", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Likely"}

    alert9.addAction(bt2)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Almost", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Almost"}

    alert9.addAction(bt3)

    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alert9.addAction(cancel9)


    //Create OK Action
    let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
        let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
        print(textfield?.text!)
        self.UselessLabel.text = textfield?.text!
    }

    alert9.addAction(ok9)

    //Add Text Field
    alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
        textfield.placeholder = "Useless"
    }

    //Present Alert Controller
    self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Please help! Im really new to Xcode and programming in general, so I'm a huge idiot when it comes to this.

Thanks :)

Comment: No offense, but if you look carefully at your code its dead simple to achieve this. Just set the `textfield.text` property to desired value instead of setting its placeholder. Simple as that.

Comment: i tried "textfield.text = self.UselessLabel.text" and that worked, but only does half the job. it allows me to edit an existing word in the label, but how would i add a preset keyword to whatever is in the label? The problem arises when i click a preset keyword, it only shows that keyword in the label and erases whatever was in there before.

Comment: Ah, that in fact is a little trickier :) you need to modify your action handlers so they append the text, rather than set a predefined constant. If you google "Swift append to label" you are bound to find something usefull ;)

Comment: oh man, im doomed haha. anyway you could help me with the code? you've already helped a lot. half the job is still pretty useful, and you answered my question, after all. i just have no idea how to code lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the placeholder with text

```
//Editable Text Box with Preset Keywords

@IBOutlet weak var UselessLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func UselessTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Useless Button Tapped")
    openUselessAlert()

}

func openUselessAlert() {

    //Create Alert Controller
    let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Uselss:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Good", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Good"}

    alert9.addAction(bt1)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Likely", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Likely"}

    alert9.addAction(bt2)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Almost", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Almost"}

    alert9.addAction(bt3)

    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alert9.addAction(cancel9)


    //Create OK Action
    let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
        let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
        print(textfield?.text!)
        self.UselessLabel.text = textfield?.text!
    }

    alert9.addAction(ok9)

    //Add Text Field
    alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
        textfield.text = "Useless"
    }

    //Present Alert Controller
    self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: OP wanted to have the text from label inserted into the textfield.